# "Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled" error at startup

Tags: boot, kernel

Whenever I boot Ubuntu, it will load properly until the display manager. After saying `gdm3.service`, it will show an error `Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled`. Many more messages appear but the system still boots normally after a while.

When I tried another kernel, a different error message also appeared. It said `Failed to start System Security Services Daemon` and mentioned some security dependencies. Later I realised that this latter error occurs only when the VMWare service failed to start.

All the articles I can find mentioning this error are outdated.

```
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 22 15:57:12 thecoder3281f-LIFEBOOK-E734 systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled. 
--Truncated output--
```

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the apport service did it for me on Ubuntu 22.10:

```
- sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

I tried the GNOME Keyring suggestion (in fact enabled all 3 gnome keyring related items in start up app) but it made no difference.

Comment: I'm just removing the bit of text about comments since a careless reviewer might misinterpret your entire answer as a comment instead of just the last sentence. And you're on your way to commenting privileges! Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Is GNOME Keyring SSH Agent selected in Startup Applications?  If not that could easily be the cause.